# Arduino C++ - call registers by arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, embedded, cpu-registers

I am using a Teensy with Teensyduino to control several stepper motors.  This requires writing to timer value registers, and there are 4 needed for each stepper.  Currently I use

```
  FTM3_C0V = val[0][0];
  FTM3_C1V = val[0][1];
  FTM3_C2V = val[0][2];
  FTM3_C3V = val[0][3];
  
  FTM3_C4V = val[1][0];
  FTM3_C5V = val[1][1];
  FTM3_C6V = val[1][2];
  FTM3_C7V = val[1][3];
```

` for this. I'd like to add a few more motors and use an array to hold the addresses of FTMx_CyV. if possible.  References to these registers are defined in a .h file as< for example

< `#define FTM3_C0V     (*(volatile uint32_t *)0x400B9010) // Channel 0 Value`
etc.

I'd appreciate any pointers (no pun intended) on how I can do this.  I have tried a number of possibilities but all have either failed to work or given me error messages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `volatile uint32_t* FTMs[] = {&FTM3_C0V, &FTM3_C1V};` looks like it should work. Then you would do `*FTMs[0] = val;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please make this an answer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It seems I can't accept a comment as an answer - but it is currently doing what I want.  Make it an answer and I'll tick it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik -  That still gives me a warning "warning: invalid conversion from 'volatile uint32_t* {aka volatile long unsigned int*}' to 'uint32_t {aka long unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]" but I'll live with it ...

Comment: A waring on which line? I don't see where such a conversion may be happening, and it shouldn't even compile in C++ (it might in C).

Comment: Apologies - a typo at my end ...

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the register array as

```
volatile uint32_t* FTM_CV[2][4] = { {&FTM3_C0V, &FTM3_C1V, &FTM3_C2V, &FTM3_C3V}, 
                                    {&FTM3_C4V, &FTM3_C5V, &FTM3_C6V, &FTM3_C7V} };
```

and referring to it with

```
void setPwms(int ph, uint8_t motor)
{
  int j = ph%16;
  *FTM_CV[motor][0] = (j < 8) ? pwmValues[j] : 0;
  *FTM_CV[motor][1] = (j < 8) ? 0 : pwmValues[j-8];
  j = (ph+4)%16;
  *FTM_CV[motor][2] = (j < 8) ? pwmValues[j] : 0;
  *FTM_CV[motor][3] = (j < 8) ? 0 : pwmValues[j-8];
}
```

seems to be working.